# Firebase delete method with insufficient permissions

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

I have the following rules for a Firestore database:

```
rules_version = '2';
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /users/{user} {
      allow create, update: if request.auth != null;
      allow read, delete, list: if request.auth.token.email == resource.data.email;
    }
  }
}
```

In my app I can read the data by using `getDocs()`, but even though the same security is on the delete function, the following does not work:

```js
const removeUser = async(number) => {
  console.log(number);
  console.log(auth.currentUser?.email || "No User");
  const usersRef = collection(db, 'users');
  const qU = query(usersRef, where('number', '==', number));
  const usersQuerySnapshot = await getDocs(qU);

  console.log(usersQuerySnapshot.docs.map(d => d.data().email);

  usersQuerySnapshot.forEach((user) => {
    deleteDoc(doc);
  });
};
```

After some debugging, I know that deleting the `deleteDoc()` lines still gives me an insufficient permissions error.

This function is called from another function, `update()`. This function also calls a `getUsersOfTeacher()` (a teacher has its own users) which uses the same code as `removeUser()` but without the deleting part. This function works with no errors.

Does anyone know what's going on here?

Comment: Can you show the minimal code with which we can reproduce the problem, and in that code show how you are meeting the requirements of the security rules you shared?

Comment: If you have emulators running it’s much easier to debug. Consider using the Firestore emulator and taking a look at the requests tab to see which line is breaking

Comment: Are you sure **all** documents matching the query have `email` same as current user's Email? It could be that only a few of the ops are failing, Can you also run `console.log(auth.currentUser?.email || "No user")` and `console.log(usersQuerySnapshot.docs.map(d => d.data().email))` and share a screenshot of the output?

Comment: @Dharmaraj If I place the first line at the top of my `removeUser()` function, I get the email of the user currently logged in. However, the other line does not run as I get the insufficient permissions error with the read as well.

Comment: @HenryHudson so the problem seems to be with the query itself? Can you try setting the rule to `allow read: if true`, run the query and the share the output? Just check if all items in the array are same as user email.

Comment: @Dharmaraj I now get `Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot use 'in' operator to search for '_delegate' in undefined`, which is not from a file that I made

Comment: The `number` seems to be `undefined` in your query. Can you update your question with the code that you are running now?

Comment: Have done. Printing `number` prints the number, not `undefined`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firebase's security [rules do not filter the data](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/rules-conditions#rules_are_not_filters). Instead they merely ensure that the code doesn't request more data than it's authorized for.

Since your rules require that the user's email address is in the `email` field of the document, your query must do the same. So something like:

```
query(
  usersRef, 
  where('number', '==', number),
  where('email', '==', auth.currentUser?.email) // 
);
```

Comment: Thanks. I also needed to write `deleteDoc(doc.ref)` rather than simply `deleteDoc(doc)`.